# PyQt --> connect() --> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: python, pyqt, connect

I have problems with connect() from PyQt4. For example here is .UI converted via pyuic4.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(382, 258)
        self.btnClearText = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btnClearText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 220, 75, 23))
        self.btnClearText.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnClearText"))
        self.btnSetText = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btnSetText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 220, 75, 23))
        self.btnSetText.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnSetText"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 361, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 361, 41))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 170, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btnSetText, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("released()")), self.textEdit_2.paste)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnClearText.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Copy", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnSetText.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Paste", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:8pt;\">ABC</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "TextLabel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And .PY file listing. Please note double-commented line. There is error, but theoretically it should work.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from simple import *

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
##        self.connect(self.btnClearText, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.label.setText('ABC'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I've got is:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Many thanks to [Luke Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48503/luke-woodward), here is a right variant.

```
class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.btnClearText, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setLabelText)
    def setLabelText(self):
        self.label.setText('ABC')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is on the double-commented line:

```
##        self.connect(self.btnClearText, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.label.setText('ABC'))
```

It looks like you want the text of the label set to `ABC` whenever the button is clicked.  However, the above line of code will not achieve this.  The problem is that the third argument, `self.label.setText('ABC')`, is evaluated when the call to `self.connect` is made, not when the signal fires.

What you've written has the same effect as

```
value = self.label.setText('ABC')
self.connect(self.btnClearText, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), value)
```

The `setText` method will always return `None`, since there's nothing to return.  The error you get arises because PyQt can't find a suitable `connect` method to call with the argument 3 set to `None` - indeed, the last three lines in your error message all mention a problem with argument 3 and `NoneType` - the 'type' of `None`.

What you could do instead is to put your code in a method, for example:

```
def setLabelText(self):
    self.label.setText('ABC')
```

Then, you use this method as argument 3 in the call to `self.connect`:

```
self.connect(self.btnClearText, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.setLabelText)
```

Note that because there is no `()` after the method name, we're not calling the method.  We're passing *the method itself* to `self.connect`.

Comment: Also please note with new style of PyQt Signals and Slots (http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) one can connect a signal and slot with a less code. So above code making signal and slot connection can be written as: self.btnClearText.clicked.connect(self.setLabelText).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've post solution in second message.